# How to move minus sign from right to left/back to front in R?

Tags: r, sign

I've imported the data from a text file and the negative numbers are in the form of 100- (The minus sign in the right side) and I should convert it into -100. Any idea. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this using `sub`.  We capture the numbers as a group (`(\\d+)`) followed by a `-` at the end (`$`) of the string and replace with `-` followed by the backreference (`\\1`) of the capture group.

```
as.numeric(sub("([0-9.]+)-$", "-\\1", v1))
#[1] -100.50 -100.05    0.22  -22.00
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(-100.5, '100.05-', 0.2200, '22.0-')
```

Comment: sub("(\\d+)(-)$", "\\2\\1", data$Revenue)                                                                          - > and my output is                                                                                        [1] "0.00 "      "148.-87"    "59.-00"     "1376.00 "   "962.00 "    "1356.00 "  
   [7] "0.00 "      "1424.00 "   "1424.00 "   "64.00 "     "214.-40"    "1497.82 "  
  [13] "2754.-00"   "36.50 "     "986.89 "    "741.00 "    "227.-00"    "394.50 "

Comment: Thanks for replying. Im new to this

Comment: @HanifAnsari  If you check my code, I have changed it, you are using the earlier code